# Is it possible to buy UK Consols (perpetuities)?

Tags: united-kingdom, government-bonds, consol

I remember learning about **[UK consols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consols)** in my finance class when we were discussing **[perpetuities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetuity)**.  Consols apparently still exist and pay 2.5% perpetually.  If I could buy a small one, I think it would be neat to have as a novelty.

All my searching for a place to purchase one led nowhere, however. I'm in the US. Might I need to be in the UK to buy one?

Comment: Think they paid all dem byatches back already.  Trust me, if they're still around, they'll bugger you to buy them.

Comment: They're perpetuaities.  They can't be paid off, they exist perpetually.  Apparently the government can call them, but they don't have a maturity date.

Comment: I'm confused as to how they can be paid off.  From the perpetuities page on Wikipedia, "A perpetuity is an annuity that has no end, or a stream of cash payments that continues forever".  See the "Real Life Examples" section where it mentions UK Consols.

Comment: Oh come on, you're not even trying.  ;))  What happens if the UK buys the debts that the UK issued?

Comment: Then they would be retired.  That's not the same as the bonds being paid off.  The UK government can't buy a Consol from me if I refuse to sell it to them.  I can just keep collecting my 2.5% forever.

Comment: However they could call them at par, it's just not rational to do so at present because they are trading under par.

Comment: The wikipedia page linked in the question says that they are often treated as perpetual bonds (i.e. perpetuity income streams).  Since it's easy to estimate a [present value of a perpetuity](http://users.wfu.edu/palmitar/Law&Valuation/chapter%201/1-3-5.htm), it's easy to buy and sell them.  If consols are sold with a provision that says HM Treasury can call them (which sounds like it's the case), then you wouldn't have a right to refuse to sell.  You could refuse to accept the purchase funds, but HM Treasury wouldn't be sending you periodic payments. Like call options or forced redemptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selftrade does [list them](https://www.selftrade.co.uk/market/gilts-bonds/gilts.php?term=undated).

Not sure if you'll be able to sign up from the US though, particularly given the [FATCA issues](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29700/isa-trading-account-options-for-us-citizens-living-in-the-uk).